# How to write condition for subquery alias if having null value

Tags: mysql, isnull

Here is my query,

```
SELECT
  `h`.`hotel_id`,
  (
  SELECT COUNT(room_id)
  FROM
    `abserve_hotel_rooms` AS `rm`
  WHERE
    `rm`.`adults_count` >= "1" AND `rm`.`room_count` >= "1" AND "Available" = IF(
      check_in_time = '2016-03-15',
      'Unavailable',
      (
        IF(
          '2016-03-15' > check_in_time,
          (
            IF(
              '2016-03-15' < check_out_time,
              'Unavailable',
              'Available'
            )
          ),
          (
            IF(
              '2016-03-22' > check_in_time,
              'Unavailable',
              'Available'
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ) AND `room_prize` BETWEEN '174' AND '600' AND `rm`.`hotel_id` = `h`.`hotel_id`
) AS `avail_room_count`,
(
SELECT MIN(room_prize)
FROM
  `abserve_hotel_rooms` AS `rm`
WHERE
  `rm`.`adults_count` >= "1" AND `rm`.`room_count` >= "1" AND "Available" = IF(
    check_in_time = '2016-03-15',
    'Unavailable',
    (
      IF(
        '2016-03-15' > check_in_time,
        (
          IF(
            '2016-03-15' < check_out_time,
            'Unavailable',
            'Available'
          )
        ),
        (
          IF(
            '2016-03-22' > check_in_time,
            'Unavailable',
            'Available'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) AND `room_prize` BETWEEN '174' AND '600' AND `rm`.`hotel_id` = `h`.`hotel_id`
) AS `min_val`
FROM
  `abserve_hotels` AS `h`
WHERE
  1 AND `city` = "madurai" AND `country` = "india"
```

It totally return one column values from my table `abserve_hotels` which is `hotel_id` with extra two alias columns such as `avail_room_count` and `min_val`..

And I wrote those in a subquery..

Here I have to check a condition `WHERE min_val IS NOT NULL` .i.e; if `min_val` having NULL value I have to restrict it

How can I do this..

And this is my table

```
hotel_id  avail_room_count  min_val   

1             0                NULL
2             0                NULL
```

Here I need to restrict these NULL values..

Someone please help me ..

Comment: Remove `sql-server` tag, if its related to my-sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause at the end:

```
HAVING min_val IS NOT NULL
```

The new query after WHERE looks like:

```
WHERE
  1 AND `city` = "madurai" AND `country` = "india"
HAVING min_val IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I tried like this way already but it shows an `#1054 - Unknown column 'min_val' in 'where clause'` error for me

Answer (score 1):

Your query is overly complex and can be much simplified:

- The two correlated sub queries are exactly the same, except for the `SELECT` list (`MIN` versus `COUNT`), so they could be combined into one;
- The aggregation done by the sub query can be done in the main query;
- The condition for checking availability can be written much shorter.

In fact, you can do all of what you need with the following query:

```
SELECT     h.hotel_id,
           COUNT(rm.room_id) as avail_room_count, 
           MIN(rm.room_prize) AS min_val
FROM       abserve_hotels AS h
INNER JOIN abserve_hotel_rooms AS rm
       ON  rm.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
WHERE      h.city = "madurai"
       AND h.country = "india"
       AND rm.adults_count >= 1 
       AND rm.room_count >= 1
       AND rm.room_prize BETWEEN 174 AND 600
       AND (   rm.check_in_time  >= '2016-03-22' 
            OR rm.check_out_time <= '2016-03-15'
            OR rm.check_in_time IS NULL) 
GROUP BY   h.hotel_id
```

Because the `INNER JOIN` requires at least one match, you can already be sure that `min_val` will never be `NULL`.

The check for availability is just as simple as:

```
           (   rm.check_in_time  >= '2016-03-22' 
            OR rm.check_out_time <= '2016-03-15'
            OR rm.check_in_time IS NULL)
```

The three parts of that condition mean:

- The reservation for this room is future and does not overlap with this week;
- The reservation for this room is in the past, the room is free today at the latest;
- The room has no known reservation.

In all three cases the room is available for reservation for the concerned week.

Comment: What table name should I specify here..Since the results are retrived from two tables `abserve_hotels` and `abserve_hotel_rooms`

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot but I follow  Dylan Su..And it works for me great..Once again Thank you  for your instant reply :)

Comment: You're welcome. When you have some time, I would still review your current query, as it is unnecessary complex, and therefore harder to maintain.